# "the user profile service failed the logon"

Tags: windows-7, login

"the user profile service failed the logon"

i had gotten this error when trying to login last night. i looked it up online and found that this was caused by an error (that is still unfound, apparently) that is causing windows to mark profiles as backup, and that the best way to fix this error is to do a system restore from the repair your computer special boot option.

what i would like to know is if there someone happens to know the cause of this error, as i would not like it to happen again.

### Computer specifications

- OS: Windows 7 hard-disk check
- completely clean "repair startup"
- scan and fix: clean, no problems
- virus scans with kaspersky: clean

(while not the usual information for specifications, i felt this info was more important for this case, any other information can be asked for.

Comment: You can try one of these solutions provided on the Microsoft Support page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur if the user profile was manually deleted by using the command prompt or by using Windows Explorer. A profile that is manually deleted does not remove the security identifier (SID) from the profile list in the registry.

Comment: as i did not remove the account, in any form, this is not helpful to my situation.

Comment: Tempting to downvote since the issue is not: Deleted user account but a service that cannot be started and preventing that user to logon. No deal with deleted user folder.