# Cannot log in to Windows 7, "User Profile Service Failed"

Tags: windows-7

I have been the only user, and original owner, of this computer and have always logged in with the same password. Randomly, yesterday, it decides that "The User Profile Service service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded." Various F8 reboot suggestions and using the On-screen Keyboard have not helped. I do not have a reset password disc or a way to enter as another user. Suggestions? Please be somewhat basic. I am a MAC user that only uses this HP as a support when necessary with certain clients.

Comment: Are you able to log into the default Administrator account.  If its disabled you will have to enable it before you can even attempt it.  This problem still exists even after a reboot?

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted many times trying different things. I don't know how to log into the default Admin acct. How can I do that?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/119199/the-user-profile-service-failed-the-logon?rq=1

Comment: Tried safe mode/last known good configuration?

Comment: How do I do that?